# mean of 10 matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I used 10 cross-validation and I tried to plot ROC but I need the mean of the predictions because I have 10 folds.

```
           N            R
 [1,] 0.6994095 0.3005905414
 [2,] 0.9874324 0.0125676441
 [3,] 0.9117558 0.0882442408
 [4,] 0.8081003 0.1918996998
 [5,] 0.9437582 0.0562418220
 [6,] 0.8711155 0.1288844516
 [7,] 0.9167169 0.0832830858
 [8,] 0.9966530 0.0033469534
 [9,] 0.9643046 0.0356954021
[10,] 0.9994098 0.0005901851
[11,] 0.7107562 0.2892437714
[12,] 0.8031399 0.1968601047
[13,] 0.5862284 0.4137715762
[14,] 0.8754098 0.1245901676
[15,] 0.7266179 0.2733820504
[16,] 0.8171662 0.1828337523
[17,] 0.8747295 0.1252705449
[18,] 0.7039327 0.2960673460
[19,] 0.8622489 0.1377510708
[20,] 0.8061929 0.1938071442
               N          R
 [1,] 0.91467687 0.08532313
 [2,] 0.94999319 0.05000681
 [3,] 0.85994831 0.14005169
 [4,] 0.92427004 0.07572996
 [5,] 0.92279287 0.07720713
 [6,] 0.15469616 0.84530384
 [7,] 0.08503478 0.91496522
 [8,] 0.90096648 0.09903352
 [9,] 0.78253348 0.21746652
[10,] 0.83780906 0.16219094
[11,] 0.02735678 0.97264322
[12,] 0.75501512 0.24498488
[13,] 0.14337626 0.85662374
[14,] 0.67239166 0.32760834
[15,] 0.79444085 0.20555915
[16,] 0.82959876 0.17040124
[17,] 0.62381221 0.37618779
[18,] 0.93198652 0.06801348
[19,] 0.80549723 0.19450277
              N            R
 [1,] 0.6474697 3.525303e-01
 [2,] 0.9999089 9.113255e-05
 [3,] 0.9641722 3.582776e-02
 [4,] 0.7305543 2.694457e-01
 [5,] 0.6486594 3.513406e-01
 [6,] 0.7024364 2.975636e-01
 [7,] 0.9235632 7.643683e-02
 [8,] 0.8051925 1.948075e-01
 [9,] 0.9945675 5.432450e-03
[10,] 0.7742103 2.257897e-01
[11,] 0.7069689 2.930311e-01
[12,] 0.9724157 2.758426e-02
[13,] 0.7592248 2.407752e-01
[14,] 0.7832677 2.167323e-01
[15,] 0.8788655 1.211345e-01
[16,] 0.8095320 1.904680e-01
[17,] 0.7962395 2.037605e-01
[18,] 0.8026804 1.973196e-01
[19,] 0.9230530 7.694699e-02
[20,] 0.8657116 1.342884e-01
              N          R
 [1,] 0.9195472 0.08045275
 [2,] 0.6775318 0.32246818
 [3,] 0.6507470 0.34925302
 [4,] 0.8885743 0.11142566
 [5,] 0.7350531 0.26494692
 [6,] 0.8004245 0.19957554
 [7,] 0.5541833 0.44581670
 [8,] 0.4774113 0.52258866
 [9,] 0.8397112 0.16028884
[10,] 0.7737221 0.22627789
[11,] 0.6968631 0.30313689
[12,] 0.6234547 0.37654533
[13,] 0.8837244 0.11627555
[14,] 0.7675875 0.23241249
[15,] 0.9442500 0.05575000
[16,] 0.6844704 0.31552959
[17,] 0.7430570 0.25694296
[18,] 0.6992994 0.30070062
[19,] 0.6573980 0.34260198
                N          R
 [1,] 0.773917644 0.22608236
 [2,] 0.859971281 0.14002872
 [3,] 0.480901800 0.51909820
 [4,] 0.863198048 0.13680195
 [5,] 0.883855903 0.11614410
 [6,] 0.573908341 0.42609166
 [7,] 0.897306073 0.10269393
 [8,] 0.870504201 0.12949580
 [9,] 0.794074784 0.20592522
[10,] 0.908536236 0.09146376
[11,] 0.001425088 0.99857491
[12,] 0.871647353 0.12835265
[13,] 0.156116706 0.84388329
[14,] 0.734450321 0.26554968
[15,] 0.576451465 0.42354853
[16,] 0.463655607 0.53634439
[17,] 0.950560375 0.04943963
[18,] 0.747841536 0.25215846
[19,] 0.941368131 0.05863187
[20,] 0.144217858 0.85578214
                N          R
 [1,] 0.981461477 0.01853852
 [2,] 0.956505434 0.04349457
 [3,] 0.268210734 0.73178927
 [4,] 0.733341695 0.26665830
 [5,] 0.433069679 0.56693032
 [6,] 0.237313097 0.76268690
 [7,] 0.610106940 0.38989306
 [8,] 0.868319458 0.13168054
 [9,] 0.963723775 0.03627623
[10,] 0.951685816 0.04831418
[11,] 0.007348949 0.99265105
[12,] 0.744557243 0.25544276
[13,] 0.383166677 0.61683332
[14,] 0.614589691 0.38541031
[15,] 0.265940109 0.73405989
[16,] 0.760060264 0.23993974
[17,] 0.775920639 0.22407936
[18,] 0.700276994 0.29972301
[19,] 0.879906317 0.12009368
               N           R
 [1,] 0.41169942 0.588300585
 [2,] 0.88863545 0.111364548
 [3,] 0.85190855 0.148091445
 [4,] 0.86718613 0.132813871
 [5,] 0.89864928 0.101350716
 [6,] 0.06688256 0.933117438
 [7,] 0.93223502 0.067764981
 [8,] 0.99141598 0.008584024
 [9,] 0.88233479 0.117665208
[10,] 0.33516056 0.664839445
[11,] 0.69588065 0.304119347
[12,] 0.82156356 0.178436441
[13,] 0.74519215 0.254807845
[14,] 0.97662100 0.023379005
[15,] 0.88235832 0.117641677
[16,] 0.96929855 0.030701449
[17,] 0.31255910 0.687440896
[18,] 0.88288702 0.117112982
[19,] 0.80102871 0.198971289
              N            R
 [1,] 0.9999485 5.151445e-05
 [2,] 0.8935091 1.064909e-01
 [3,] 0.8862276 1.137724e-01
 [4,] 0.8211438 1.788562e-01
 [5,] 0.9311932 6.880675e-02
 [6,] 0.8675625 1.324375e-01
 [7,] 0.8856136 1.143864e-01
 [8,] 0.8135479 1.864521e-01
 [9,] 0.9050920 9.490801e-02
[10,] 0.2020622 7.979378e-01
[11,] 0.9886441 1.135591e-02
[12,] 0.8716919 1.283081e-01
[13,] 0.7141835 2.858165e-01
[14,] 0.6755985 3.244015e-01
[15,] 0.2744007 7.255993e-01
[16,] 0.8592688 1.407312e-01
[17,] 0.9179941 8.200594e-02
[18,] 0.7902478 2.097522e-01
[19,] 0.5800900 4.199100e-01
              N          R
 [1,] 0.8805678 0.11943219
 [2,] 0.8517081 0.14829192
 [3,] 0.9830331 0.01696693
 [4,] 0.8223849 0.17761507
 [5,] 0.9638743 0.03612568
 [6,] 0.8545500 0.14545004
 [7,] 0.6056922 0.39430778
 [8,] 0.9077465 0.09225346
 [9,] 0.9138271 0.08617288
[10,] 0.7173141 0.28268590
[11,] 0.8547256 0.14527435
[12,] 0.9870370 0.01296299
[13,] 0.7568859 0.24311411
[14,] 0.7389089 0.26109106
[15,] 0.4960564 0.50394361
[16,] 0.2751176 0.72488239
[17,] 0.7197224 0.28027763
[18,] 0.8987683 0.10123174
[19,] 0.7769943 0.22300568
[20,] 0.8007028 0.19929716
               N          R
 [1,] 0.79091397 0.20908603
 [2,] 0.60712842 0.39287158
 [3,] 0.79979195 0.20020805
 [4,] 0.55740147 0.44259853
 [5,] 0.83137224 0.16862776
 [6,] 0.36536631 0.63463369
 [7,] 0.75064646 0.24935354
 [8,] 0.81430815 0.18569185
 [9,] 0.68985973 0.31014027
[10,] 0.73377876 0.26622124
[11,] 0.07613196 0.92386804
[12,] 0.95714924 0.04285076
[13,] 0.98379127 0.01620873
[14,] 0.84372946 0.15627054
[15,] 0.75142544 0.24857456
[16,] 0.35243540 0.64756460
[17,] 0.20153258 0.79846742
[18,] 0.59625005 0.40374995
[19,] 0.85515909 0.14484091
```

So I have 10 matrices from predictions and I need a mean of each row and column to be one matrix. 
I used (colMean) function but it gives me a mean of all column so the final matrix will be 10 rows and it should be 20 rows.

```
        N         R 
0.8432539 0.1567461 
        N         R 
0.6797998 0.3202002 
        N         R 
0.8244347 0.1755653 
        N         R 
0.7377374 0.2622626 
        N         R 
0.6746954 0.3253046 
        N         R 
0.6387108 0.3612892 
        N         R 
0.7480788 0.2519212 
        N         R 
0.7830537 0.2169463 
        N         R 
0.7902809 0.2097191 
        N         R 
0.6609564 0.3390436
```

how can I get the mean of each row on 10 matrices?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want. But if you provided a minimal reproducible example it would help a lot.

Comment: I need a mean of 10 matrices

Comment: What is the exact operation you want to perform? In general, you need to split this into two operations. (1) move all your data into a vector, and (2) perform the `mean` function on the vector. The "mean of each row and column" implies that you are trying to do the mean of one value at a time. If you'd like to do the column mean of EACH column, @Max Ft has a good solution that is simple. The `lapply` is step 1, and the function you'd like to perform (row mean or column mean) is step 2.

Comment: because I used 10 cross validation I got 10 ROC, and I need the mean of prediction to get 1 ROC

Answer (score 2):

There is a `rowMeans` function that work with matrices.

```
m = matrix(1:6,nrow=2)
l = list(m,m)
lapply(l,rowMeans)
```

You can `unlist` the output to get a vector and you can convert the vector into a matrix if you want a matrix in the end. Like this:

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(l,rowMeans)),nrow=nrow(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the arrays in an array and apply a rowMeans loop

```
A = array(data = NA, dim = c(20,2,10));dimnames(A)[[2]] = c("N","R")
for(i in  1:10){A[,,] <- cbind(N = runif(20), R = runif(20))}

res = matrix(data = NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 10)
for(i in 1:10){res[,i] <- rowMeans(A[,,i])}
res
```